# Can we [link] these two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

We have two tags that, to my mind, are identical for all practical purposes.

[hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink)

> Wiki: A hyperlink is a reference to a document (or a section) that can be followed for retrieval using a navigation system that allows selecting emphasized content within an originating document.

[href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/href)

> Wiki: Hyperlink (or link) is a reference to a document that the reader can directly follow, or that is followed automatically.

This being the case, it seems to me that [href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/href) should be made a synonym of [hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink).

Comment: I would argue that hyperlink should be the synonym since "hyperlink" is how non-programmers refer to it when 99% of the time a developer will reference the `href` attribute of an anchor tag in HTML or their framework-of-the-month's way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that these should not be synonymized.

A hyperlink does not have to be realized in HTML. You can create hyperlinks in many user interface technologies (I remember creating them in Winforms in VB5 back in the day) that may or may not use an `href` property or attribute to set the destination.

Additionally the `href` attribute is not only used to create hyperlinks; it is also used to load resources (as in the `link` element with a `rel="stylesheet"` attribute) for a document, among other uses.

I would support burninating the [href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/href) tag however. Its use does not help categorize questions significantly enough to make a difference.

Comment: Windows Forms in [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) also has it: class `System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel`. [Example](http://pmortensen.eu/1/MSQuant/MSQsrcWWW,1.5,2008-12-19/formAbout.vb.html). There isn't any special syntax for the URL.

Comment: @PeterMortensen so does office products, but I presume they are stored in a xml element which I'm not privy of.